# LDAP mounting home over network

Tags: ldap

Guys i am working with LDAP and was successful in making the user logging in using PAM but how can i sync the directories so that if the user logs in and saves any data in his home folder can access all his data by logging in anywhere in the network.
Ultimately i want that the LDAP user can access his home data anywhere in the network.

Answer (score 1):

Your server containing the home directories can share them via NFS and the clients can mount them.